# Pandas check if the sum of two columns within the same group equals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a purchase record table showing the purchasing history recorded by customers and the store. I would like to get a new column where it shows the sum of the customer records & store records from each customer, as a group, equals. So basically 5 + 3 = 5 + 3 so Yes for 001 but 2 != 3 so No for 002.

| Date | custID | itmID | cust rec | store rec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0514 | 001 | A | 5 | 5 |
| 0514 | 001 | B | 3 | 3 |
| 0514 | 002 | A | 2 | 3 |

expected result:

| Date | custID | itmID | cust rec | store rec | sum match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0514 | 001 | A | 5 | 5 | Yes |
| 0514 | 001 | B | 3 | 3 | Yes |
| 0514 | 002 | A | 2 | 3 | No |

my code:

```
df['sum match'] = (sum(df['store rec'])==sum(df['cust rec'])).groupby(match.custID)
```

error shows `'bool' object has no attribute 'groupby'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby and transform sum and then check difference of the columns on axis=1. then get the last result to check if it is 0 and conditionally assign values to the new column:

```
c = (df.groupby("custID")[['cust rec','store rec']]
      .transform('sum').diff(axis=1).iloc[:,-1].eq(0))

df['sum match'] = np.where(c,"Yes",'No')
```

---

**output:**

```
print(df)

   Date  custID itmID  cust rec  store rec sum match
0   514       1     A         5          5       Yes
1   514       1     B         3          3       Yes
2   514       2     A         2          3        No
```

---

More details of the steps:

Groupby + transform sum returns sum of each group per column:

```
print(df.groupby("custID")[['cust rec','store rec']].transform('sum'))

   cust rec  store rec
0         8          8
1         8          8
2         2          3
```

then difference on axis=1:

```
print(df.groupby("custID")[['cust rec','store rec']].transform('sum').diff(axis=1))
   cust rec  store rec
0       NaN        0.0
1       NaN        0.0
2       NaN        1.0
```